# TDD on Standard Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, html, tdd

I have a question related to TDD on 'Standard Javscript/HTML' functions.

Given I have this function:

```
function ContainerHandler(elDivContainer){
    this.elContainer = elDivContainer;
    //...Register events to the given container and do some other fancy stuff...
};

ContainerHandler.prototype.getScrollTop = function(){
    return this.elContainer.scrollTop;
};
ContainerHandler.prototype.setScrollTop = function(iScrollTop){
    this.elContainer.scrollTop = iScrollTop;
};
ContainerHandler.prototype.getBoundingClientRect = function(){
    return this.elContainer.getBoundingClientRect();
};
```

Now, my question would be, how do I write meaningful and appropriate tests for the functions that 'proxy' the standard javascript functions as above? Currently what I am doing is basically just inputing a dummy div into the constructor and checking whether the output of the functions correspond to the same properties I have defined on my dummy div, however, I am not quite sure if this is enough. Do you guys have any better approach on this situation?

Thank you very much in advance!

Frank

Comment: in my opinion this is not TDD. you don't need to test base functionality or implementation.

Comment: @webduvet Hey, thanks for the input. I actually started developing this by writing the tests. So my line of thinking was basically: 'Ok, I need a class that wraps the container div that is build by the renderer, then I have to have a function to get the current scrollTop, and a function to set the scrollTop and bla bla bla..', hence I have tests for this and the way I found to implement it is basically as above. Also, the code above is not the actual code I have implemented, but is the same idea/structure.

Comment: You should only test things that could possibly break -- in this case these methods are so trivial that one wouldn't bother. If you do really want to test them then you'd have to pass in a mock container and confirm that the correct methods are invoked

Comment: @EngineerDollery Thanks for the Input! I partially agree with you, but what comes to my mind is. Maybe at some point somebody wants to add an offset on the returned value of these functions, example, transform the rect before returning it. If this happens, and there are other functions depending on this API, something weird might happen, and if there aren't any tests for this, it might be a little bit tricky to troubleshoot. Does this scenario make sense? Or I am being to strict on testing stuff? Thanks!